# How to Determine Intersection of 2 Solids in Python

Tags: python, solidworks

I have 2 solids defined as STL files:

1. The first solid is a cube defined by 8 vertices (each vertex represented as numpy array) and 12 triangles (2 for each cube face)
2. The second solid is also a cube defined by 8 vertices and 12 triangles (2 for each cube face)

The task is to create a Python function to determine the volume of intersection of these 2 solids. How to do this one?

Comment: If you could use something else than solidworks and have the same problem, you have to remove the tag.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: I haven't tried any code yet and still researching how to actually code the program.